# Java code PMD complains as Method should have only one exit point

Tags: java, performance, pmd

```
public boolean validate(final Beanform[] bagdata) {
        final int length = bagdata.length;
        if (length == 4) {
            return true;
        } else if (length == 1) {
            result = "length==1, Length should be greater than 1";
            return false;
        } else if (length == 3) {
            if (bagdata[0].getCycleType() == null) {
            result = "Cyclic Type is null for length==3";
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Hi ,

The above is piece of java code , that is working fine .
However when i ran the code aganist PMD .
A method should have only one exit point, and that should be the last statement in the method

Could you anybody please tell me how to mould this code , so that 
it follows A method should have only one exit point, and that should be the last statement in the method
And what  is the best prtacie in this types of code ??

please share your experience on this .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure it didn't say that your method should only have one *exit* point?

The code you've shown has only one entry point, but 4 exit points.

---

Update:  we're talking about exit points.

First, just because a tool tells you that it doesn't like your **working** code doesn't mean it's right and you're wrong.  The single/multiple exit point debate has a long history; both are probably right to a certain extent.  In other words, **don't fix what ain't broke!**

But if you do want to appease PMD, here's what you could do:

- declare a boolean variable, i.e. `isValid`, at the top of your method
- replace every `return true/false` statement with `isValid = true/false`
- at the end of the method, `return isValid`

Comment: I am sorry for troubling others , the actual comment is "A method should have only one exit point, and that should be the last statement in the method" now let me modify the question .

Comment: Thank you very much Matt Fenwick for answering , now i guess wha i did is right instead of adding a extra boolean variable.

Comment: If you're interested in why PMD has this suggestion, please see this related question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from

Comment: @RyanTenney -- wow, 200 upvotes in 2 days!  Thanks for the link.

Comment: don't fix what ain't broke is not, IMHO, right. What is true is that you should have a test to refactor anything before change a code that is not broken.

Comment: @ernesto -- you're missing the point of the OP/answer.  Your project could have fantastic test coverage for your method, and your entire team could agree that the method is well-written and clear .... but then PMD comes along and says it's bad because of multiple `return`s.  Who are you going to trust?  *Is it broken?*